# How to receive images via Bluetooth

Tags: android, image, bluetooth, receiver

I want to receive images via Bluetooth and display that image in Image View.I know how to pass image from one activity to another activity but i don't no how to receive images using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Android framework provides access to the Bluetooth functionality through the Android Bluetooth APIs. These APIs let applications wirelessly connect to other Bluetooth devices, enabling point-to-point and multipoint wireless features.

Using the Bluetooth APIs, an Android application can perform the following:

- Scan for other Bluetooth devices
- Query the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices
- Establish RFCOMM channels
- Connect to other devices through service discovery
- Transfer data to and from other devices
- Manage multiple connections

> Create a BluetoothSocket and connect to it:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(<your-device>.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
socket.connect();
```

> Listen to the socket (Get data from the device)

```
InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
while (inStream.available() > 0) {
    inStream.read(); // <-- data from device
}
```

> Write to the socket (Send data to the device)

```
OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = <some-data>
outStream.write(bytes);
```

and for more details you can read [Bluetooth Api Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)